# Angular - Progressive Web app hard refresh (ctrl + f5)

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I built an angular app with pwa and i add it with the following steps: 
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

I add the following code to app.component.ts:

```
if (swPush.isEnabled) {

  swPush.subscription.subscribe((subscription: PushSubscription) => {
    if (!subscription) {
      swPush
        .requestSubscription({
          serverPublicKey: VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY,
        })
        .then((subscription: PushSubscription) => {
          service.sendSubscriptionToTheServer(subscription);
        })
        .catch(console.error)
    }
  });
```

I discovered that when i press hard refresh in browser

```
swPush.subscription.subscribe
```

not fire.

Why is this happening? Is there a solution to this so that it is still fire if i press hard refresh?